# How to change dataflow parameter in Power BI via dataflow settings?

Tags: powerbi

Inside a Data flow we can create parameters. However once dataflow is created, in the settings there is no option to set parameter value.

How to configure dataflow parameter in Power BI?

Comment: You have to edit the dataflow to update the parameters.  They aren't represented in the settings.  In my case I have a simple parameter that takes an hour to change because of the dumb "validating" step that occurs while saving dataflows.